# How do I get the value of sh. isBalancerRunning() in MongoDB using Java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, bigdata

I am trying to get the value for sh.isBalancerRunning() by the below code but it is not returning error results.

```
    String list = db.command("isBalancerRunning").toString();
    BasicDBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject("isBalancerRunning","1");
    list =mongoClient.getDB("admin").command(cmd).toString();
```

Comment: It's [`"balancerStatus"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/balancerStatus/#dbcmd.balancerStatus) and not `"isBalancerRunning"`. If you are ever looking for what "shell helpers" are actually doing, then simply type them in without the trailing brackets `()` ie. `sh.isBalancerRunning`. This will show the defined JavaScript function in the shell, which in this case merely wraps the command invocation on the admin database ( as you suspected ) but of course shows the actual command being used. Of course all commands are documented in the manual under the provided link as well.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.isBalancerRunning/ -> How to get this value in Java

Comment: `BasicDBObject("balancerStatus", 1)`. This is what you were just told.